# ASP.NET MVC 3: Purpose of IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); ? deprecated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Do I even need this rule anymore?
I don't see any requests incoming for resource.axd files (as opposed to when I ran webform applications)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> WebResource.axd is an HTTP Handler that is part of the .NET Framework
>   that does one thing and one thing only – it is tasked with getting an
>   embedded resource out of a DLL and returning its content. What DLL to
>   go to and what embedded resource to take are specified through the
>   querystring. For instance, a request to
>   www.yoursite.com/WebResource.axd?d=EqSMS…&t=63421… might return a
>   particular snippet of JavaScript embedded in a particular assembly.

Its still part of the framework and you can still retrieve embedded resources using the above handler. You dont want your route handler to handle such requests and that is why it is ignored. My guess is that you can get rid of it if you are completely sure that your app/libraries that you use dont use it.